# Deleting A Folder - How To?

Tags: vba, directory

This is the code I'm using to remove / delete a folder located on the desktop :

```
Option Explicit

Sub deletefiles()
Dim fso As Object
Dim folder 'As String
Dim f
Dim Name As String

On Error Resume Next

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder = fso.GetFolder("C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs")  '<-- edit path as required to match your machine

' delete all files in root folder
For Each f In folder.Files
   On Error Resume Next
   Name = f.Name
   f.Delete True

   On Error GoTo 0
Next

' delete all subfolders and files
For Each f In folder.SubFolders
   On Error Resume Next
   Name = f.Name
   f.Delete True

   On Error GoTo 0
Next

folder.Delete

End Sub
```

The macro does the job of deleting files in the folder ... EXCEPT for deleting the folder itself. The folder isn't actually gone from the desktop until I close the workbook.

Why ?  How do I change the code so I don't have to close the workbook first ?

Thank you.

ps: A working macro doesn't have to be the one above. I'll accept ANY code that works.

==========================================================================

**UPDATE**

Here is the entire code for create PDF, email and delete :

```
Option Explicit

Sub pdf()
Dim wsA As Worksheet, wbA As Workbook, strTime As String
Dim strName As String, strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim strPathFile As String


'On Error GoTo errHandler

    Set wbA = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsA = ActiveSheet


'replace spaces and periods in sheet name
    strName = Replace(wsA.Name, " ", "")
    strName = Replace(strName, ".", "_")

'create default name for savng file
    'strPath = "G:\Finance\Corporate Accounting\SHIRLEY\A. Financial Planning Fee Payment Processing\"
    strPath = "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs\"
    strFile = strName    '"_" & strTime & "_" & Sheets("MDM Invoice").Range("B2").Value
    strPathFile = strPath & strFile


Dim myFolder$
myFolder = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\PDFs"

If Dir(myFolder, vbDirectory) = "" Then
     MkDir myFolder
End If

'export to PDF if a folder was selected
    wsA.ExportAsFixedFormat 0, strPathFile

'confirmation message with file info
    MsgBox "PDF file has been created: " _
      & vbCrLf _
      & strPathFile

exitHandler:
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    MsgBox "Could not create PDF file"
    Resume exitHandler
End Sub

Sub Send_Email()

Dim FileName As String
Dim strPath As String, strPath2 As String
Dim c As Range
Dim OutLookApp As Object
Dim OutLookMailItem As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim it As String

strPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\PDFs\"
strPath2 = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\PDFs"

    For Each c In Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Cells
        Set OutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
        Set OutLookMailItem = OutLookApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutLookMailItem
                .To = "logitga@yahoo.com"  'c.Value
                .CC = "Your CC here"
                .Subject = "Your Subject here"
                .HTMLBody = "Your Body content here"
                FileName = Dir(strPath & "*.*")

                .Attachments.Add strPath & FileName
                .Display
                '.Send
        End With
    Next c
On Error Resume Next

Kill "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs\*.*"    ' delete all files in the folder
RmDir "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs"  ' delete folder
End Sub

Sub byby()
'Dim fso
'    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'    fso.DeleteFolder Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\PDFs"

Kill "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs\*.*"    ' delete all files in the folder
RmDir "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs"  ' delete folder
End Sub
```

Comment: Disregard this entry.

Comment: @Jerry, you can post an answer to your own question if you figured out the solution yourself.

Comment: I tried this macro ... Option Explicit

Sub byby()
Dim fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fso.deletefolder Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\PDFs"
End Sub

But it too won't completely remove the folder until I close the workbook. Why ?

Comment: Is the workbook residing within the folder?

Comment: The first step of debugging is to remove/comment all the `On Error Resume Next` instances so you can figure out what goes wrong.

Comment: Workbook is not in the folder being deleted.    There are no errors in the code.   If it has an affect on the folder deletion, this is the last action in a VBA email process. The file being attached to the VBA email is located in the folder PDFs. Once the email is sent, the file then the folder are to be deleted in preparation for next use.

Comment: It is almost like the macro or whatever is waiting for the workbook to "step out of the folder" ... "change its focus elsewhere" ... or something like "close the folder" before it is willing to delete the folder.  I've not experienced this before.

Answer (score 0):

To remove a folder you should use the [RmDir Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/rmdir-statement). According to the documentation:

> An error occurs if you try to use RmDir on a directory or folder containing files. Use the [Kill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/kill-statement) statement to delete all files before attempting to remove a directory or folder.

So you end up with a routine like:

```
Kill "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs\*.*"    ' delete all files in the folder
RmDir "C:\Users\My\Desktop\PDFs"  ' delete folder
```

Comment: When I use the KILL and the RmDir commands, I am still faced with the same issue of having to close the workbook for the parent folder to be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

## Object vs Variant

Just change the lines 5 & 6 to:

```
Dim folder As Object
Dim f As Object
```

That probably happened due to some copy pasting or whatever.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Still having to close the workbook before the folder is gone from the desktop.

Comment: Try adding 'MsgBox folder.Attributes'  a line before 
'folder.Delete'

Comment: It was working fine. Then I set the attributes of the folder to read-only and couldn't get rid of it. The result of folder.Attributes was 17, 16 for folder and 1 for read-only. Now I used folder.delete True and got rid of the folder Well, try folder.delete True

Comment: Try releasing the variables: Set f = Nothing: Set folder=Nothing: Set fso = Nothing

Comment: VBasic2008 :  Tried all ... still no go.  My workbook is POSSESSED !

Comment: I think it has something to do with permissions and a process has locked the file(folder). I don't think it's outlook, I think it's excel or maybe office. The permission thing happens when you save the file to a folder. It's too advanced for me so I dropped it after a too considerable amount of time. Sorry.

Comment: That is ok. I've resigned myself to saving the temp folder at C:\ instead of on the desktop. That way my OCD brain won't actually see it and it still gets deleted when the workbook is closed.

Comment: THANK YOU !  everyone for your assistance. Deeply appreciated.